# How to allow tkinter Label or Message widget to split words when wrapping

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, word-wrap

I would look to display a path to a file in the tkinter application i'm developing and would like the `Label` or `Message` widget not to wrap the text when it sees a space character but instead when the text exceeds the set `wraplength`.

Currently when i'm displaying a really long path it does it like this:

`Current file:
/home/exampleName/A-Path/A-Really-long-Path/Running-out-ideas/ok-another-directory/my_file.txt`

but instead i would prefer if it would display like this:

`Current file: /home/exampleName/A-Path/A-Really-long-Path/Running-out-ideas/ok-another-directory/my_file.txt`

any ideas or suggestions? Thanks for your help i would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: I don't think tkinter has anything specifically to handle something like this. A workaround might be to use the [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#module-textwrap) module to pre-wrap the text in two multiple lines before you put in the widget.

Comment: Use **2** `Label`, one for `Current file:` and one with `wraplength` for `/home/exampleName...`.